# php curl - how to get simple page redirect

Tags: php, curl

Trying to create proxy, which should works just as redirect to specific page by form submit.
Wrote the following:

```
<?php
$postdata = filter_input_array( INPUT_POST );
if( count( $postdata ) == 0 ) die();

$curl = curl_init();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $postdata[ "processor" ], // Here is redirect URL
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postdata
);
curl_setopt_array( $curl, $options );
curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );
?>
```

I see in Google Chrome Developer console that response absolutely correct, but I didn't see it properly in browser.
What's wrong?

Comment: if you wanna redirect the page simple use header() method of PHP. Curl allows you to visit a page programmatically but if you simple wanna do redirect use `header("Location:url");` in php. IF you wanna get that page and display on your php site then you need to parse the result of the curl and display.

Comment: Need to put form fields post (encapsulated into postdata array) then redirects to specific URL - same as form submit did

Comment: Put `header( "Location:" . $postdata[ "processor" ] );` just before  curl_init. This produces error:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ...

Comment: Why dont you use simply html form to submit data to URL.? First form submit data and url and on second page get that url , put on action and auto submit using JS. Two HTML form you need in this case

Comment: Source of fields - some of JS frameworks (webix). I don't understand why their ajax.post didn't work. The only thing I can do - call PHP proxy within JS code; call works well, parameters put also as required.

Comment: Use cookie jar in curl

Answer (score 0):

Redirect after completion, check CURL status code as 200.

```
    $postdata = filter_input_array( INPUT_POST );
    if( count( $postdata ) == 0 ) die();

    $curl = curl_init();
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $postdata[ "processor" ], // Here is redirect URL
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postdata
    );
    curl_setopt_array( $curl, $options );
    curl_exec( $curl );
    curl_close( $curl );
    header("Location:".$postdata[ "processor" ]);
```

Make sure not output/prints before header(); You can validate your CURL status code from your curl detail and then redirect if 200. 
**See how to get curl detail with status code** [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)
**Redirect example :** [Link](http://blog.eexit.net/curl-forward-post-over-http-redirections/)

Comment: I know - this page will work.
But finally - curl can't redirect pages? I read that curl can do it, but unclear - how to do it?

Comment: header must be at the end to redirect the page after completion of your CURL operation

Comment: Sorry, last code with header() at the end has no effect

Comment: are you sure you have url `$postdata[ "processor" ]` and put full url with `http://`